# Scoping variables in a Perl Test::More .t file

Tags: perl, unit-testing

Is there a way to scope variables for Test::More tests in a .t file? For example:

```
# 1st Test
$gotResult = $myObject->runMethod1();
$expectedResult = "value1";
is($gotResult, $expectedResult, "validate runMethod1()");

#2nd Test
$gotResult = $myObject->runMethod2();
$expectedResult = "value2";
is($gotResult, $expectedResult, "validate runMethod2()");

#3rd Test
...
```

I'm looking for a way to discretely manage the individual tests in a .t file so conflicts/errors are not introduced if variable names are reused between tests.

Sal.

Answer (score 8):

To expand on mirod's correct answer: you may scope variables with braces as you would for any Perl program, however you may take it a step further. [Test::More](https://metacpan.org/module/Test%3a%3aMore) has the concept of a subtest, in which you define a subref which contains one or more tests which run together (and of course creating a scope in the process).

```
subtest 'Subtest description here' => sub {
  # do some setup, then do some tests
  ok 1, 'the simplest test';
};
```

Comment: Awesome, looking forward to trying the subtest approach.

Comment: A large-scale example may be seen in my repo for Galileo, [here](https://github.com/jberger/Galileo/blob/master/t/basic.t). Don't let the Test::Mojo syntax worry you, its really using Test::More underneath.

Answer (score 5):

Wrap each test in braces:

```
{ # test1 ...
}

{ # test 2 ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks, didn't realize it was that simple.

Comment: @Sal. Perl test files are just normal Perl programs.